# Having trouble running my Django app

Tags: python, django

I am learning to build a Django app named rango from the site http://www.tangowithdjango.com/ , but things are bit different as I am using Django 1.9 which is not same as in the tutorial, so I am facing difficulty in running the app. Whenever I run the server, it gives error as

```
 NameError: name 'rango' is not defined
```

I have included rango in the INSTALLED_APPS list. Here is my master urls.py file's code:

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^rango/', include(rango.urls)),
]
```

And here is my local urls.py file (rango's urls.py) that is kept within the /rango folder:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views

urlpatterns=patterns('',
    url(r'^$',views.index,name='index'),)
```

So why is my rango app not being located?

Comment: In your master `urls.py` you are not importing rango module, that's why.

Comment: Do you have an init.py file in your rango app?

Comment: you must import rango.urls or quote it. `include('rango.urls')` is the best way. You also no long need `patterns('', ...)`

Comment: @AnirbanAcharya Which line and file does it point to when it gives the`NameError: name 'rango' is not defined` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the `rango.urls` has to be in quotes. So your master `urls.py` should look like this -

```
from django.conf.urls import include,url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^rango/', include('rango.urls')),
]
```

Comment: This is incorrect and in fact this isn't supported in the latest django version

Comment: `rango.urls` doesn't have to be in quotes.

Comment: @Eagllus the official docs say so https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/#write-your-first-view

Notice the `polls.urls` in quotes